# api de google maps obtener localizaciones de tiendas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api, google-maps

### hay algun filtro para la api de maps?

*mi idea es poner el mapa con la latitud y longitud de la persona que visita la web*

sabiendo esto, hay alguna manera de poner por ejemplo los bares
cercanos con marcadores en la api de maps

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBQfylU9wxc8bzsFjYD1nyAOrFURTsf--w&libraries=places&callback=funcionMapas"
 async defer></script>

<script>        
      var map;
      var autocomp;
     function funcionMapas() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 43.380246, lng: -3.744807},
          zoom: 12,
        });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
                    var latLng = event.latLng;
                    localStorage.setItem('Latitude', latLng.lat())
                    localStorage.setItem('Longitude', latLng.lng())
                });

 
      }
    </script>
```

Esto es lo que tengo de momento, gracias un saludo